# Stream pdf to Web Browser Control C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have been searching  on this subject and note that no one has really answered this, thus I am asking the question here.

I have a restful method that returns a pdf as a bytes, which in the http response I save to Stream. This Stream I point to my Web browser control using the document stream property and call the doevents method.

Unfortunately, this returns rubbish. Is it possible to have the browser control to render a pdf file by sending a stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the it was due the browser IE8. Everything works in IE9